# Maximum difference between rows

Tags: sql

I am not strong with SQL at all, so here it goes:

I have a table with a column containing doubles.
I would like to select all rows that the maximum difference between them is '5'.

How can I do that?

```
id         value

 1         4955.54
 2         2884.32
 3         8485.45
 4         4588.54
 5         8487.62
```

RESULT

```
 id        value

 3         8485.45
 5         8487.62
```

How can I do that in mySQL ?
Many thanks!

Comment: Your requirement is probably not complete. What would happen with record `6 8491.00`? It is within the accepted range of `id=5` but not within the accepted range of `id=3`. Besides, from your example result, I think you want to select the rows whose "maximum difference is 5", not "minimum"

Comment: of course its maximum. Edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, although you mean *maximum* not *minimum* difference:

```
SELECT v.id, v.value 
FROM Values v 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT null from Values v2 
    WHERE v2.id <> v.id and
    ABS(v2.value - v.value) BETWEEN 0 AND 5
)
```

- [MSDN: EXISTS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)
- [MSDN: ABS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx)
- [MSDN: BETWEEN (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, value from table t1 
  inner join table t2 on t1.id <> t2.id
 where ABS(t1.value-t2.value)<=5
```

Comment: the where clause Should be <= 5

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to be inefficient if the set of values is large. There is no obvious way to write this query efficiently, but here goes:

```
select     lo.val
,          hi.val
from       numbers lo
inner join numbers hi
on         hi.val - lo.val >= 5
```

if the val column is indexed, it might help to add another condition like so:

```
select     lo.val
,          hi.val
from       numbers lo
inner join numbers hi
on         hi.val > lo.val 
where      hi.val - lo.val >= 5
```

Comment: he wants to get both the high and low value that are within 5... your solution doesn't do that... it gets all the ones that are over 5... so you get the opposite set of what he is looking for... despite how the question is worded... the expected results show differently...

Comment: @jsobo: I agree. The question is mis-phrased.